# Unable to resize a vim tab inside tmux

Tags: linux, vim, tmux, vim-plugin, nerdtree

I have Vim opened in a tmux session. In Vim I have nerd-tree(project explorer plugin) installed. When I open the files as tabs in vim, I am unable to resize the tabs using mouse drag. I think some property of tmux is overwriting the vim mouse commmands.

I tried to disable the mouse scroll in tmux and then resize. Still couldnot fix the issue.

Comment: sorry it may be a stupid suggestion, but have you enabled the mouse for all modes (:set mouse=a) ?